Indexing a binary and searching with contains, cannot find results
I would like to ask for your help in understanding where I go wrong in building a working example where I populate a repository with binary data, index it, and run a contains query.
I have logs to TRACE and I see the indexing working, upon executing the query however I always get 0 results.
Repository is MemoryNodeStore and I create it in this way:
LuceneIndexProvider provider = new LuceneIndexProvider();
Oak oak = new Oak(ns) // ns is a NodeStore MemoryNodeStore
.with((QueryIndexProvider) provider)
.with((Observer) provider)
.with(new LuceneIndexEditorProvider());
repository = new Jcr(oak).createRepository();

Then I populate it in this way:
Node node = rootNode.addNode("node" + i, "nt:unstructured");
byte[] data = ("testo" + i).getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
Binary binary = session.getValueFactory().createBinary(bais);
try {
    node.setProperty("binaryData", binary);

} finally {
    binary.dispose();
}
node.setProperty("jcr:mimeType", "text/plain");

Then the index is in this way:
Node root = session.getRootNode();
Node oakIndex = root.getNode("oak:index");
Node index = oakIndex.addNode("contentTextIndex", "oak:QueryIndexDefinition");
index.setProperty("type", "lucene");
index.setProperty("async", (String[]) null);
Node indexRules = index.addNode("indexRules", "nt:unstructured");
Node ntBase = indexRules.addNode("nt:base", "nt:unstructured");
Node properties = ntBase.addNode("properties", "nt:unstructured");
Node binaryDataProperty = properties.addNode("binaryData", "nt:unstructured");
binaryDataProperty.setProperty("name", "binaryData";
binaryDataProperty.setProperty("propertyIndex", true);
binaryDataProperty.setProperty("analyzed", true);
Node jcrMimeTypeProperty = properties.addNode("jcr:mimeType");
jcrMimeTypeProperty.setProperty("name", "jcr:mimeType");
jcrMimeTypeProperty.setProperty("propertyIndex", true);
jcrMimeTypeProperty.setProperty("analyzed", true);

Then I search in this way:
String sql2QueryString = "SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE CONTAINS([binaryData], 'testo')";
Query sql2Query = queryManager.createQuery(sql2QueryString, Query.JCR_SQL2);
QueryResult result = sql2Query.execute();

and I read the results in this way:
NodeIterator nodes = result.getNodes();
while (nodes.hasNext()) {
    Node node = nodes.nextNode();
    log.info("Path: " + node.getPath());
    counter++;
}
log.info("Found {} results", counter);

I'm using oak 1.68.0 with tika-core and tika-parsers-standard-package 2.9.2.
In logs I see the indexing and the text extraction correctly, if you want I can attach a full log.
Really thank you for your help, best regards

Could you replace "propertyName" in the code with a constant? And index.setProperty("async", (String[]) null); will remove that property; I think you should use "async" or so.

When running the query, is the correct index used? You can check with "explain select ...". One way to ensure the right index is used is if you add a "tag" to the query and the index.

@ThomasMueller Why should I replace propertyname with a constant? propertyName is a String variable representing the name of the property I want to index.
That async setting is needed in my junit test to index immediately, I know that in a production env I should use async, anyway the indexing is done successfully, TRACE logs telle me that.
Yes I'm sure query use my index, TRACE logs tell me that too

Well in the code above (in the question) we need to know what propertyName is. Is it "x"?

Ok Thomas I did, the index is on the property named "binaryData"

This area was not clear to me either (I didn't implement this part, and the people that did left, and didn't properly document it). I found the problem, and updated the documentation. I hope it will now work, and I hope the documentation is clear now!

I found that the documentation was misleading. I tried to fix it.

If the aggregation rules are set, for binary data, you do not need to include it separately. When using aggregation, binary properties are automatically added to the fulltext index (but only there), if the mime type is set, and if the node is part of the index.
If aggregation rules are not used, then you need to set nodeScopeIndex to true for the property (see example).
You need to query the fulltext index using eg. SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'testo1')
You have added "testo" + i so you also need to query for that, e.g. testo1 (see above), not testo.
Setting analyzed and propertyIndex for binary properties has no effect. They will not be added added to a property index or fulltext index for this property; they will only be added to the fulltext index for this node (document).
You do not need to index the jcr:mimeType property if you do not have queries for it. A query on the this property would have a condition with jcr:mimeType.

Example index definition:
  "/oak:index/contentTextIndex": {
    "compatVersion": 2,
    "type": "lucene",
    "tags": ["text"],
    "async": ["async"],
    "queryPaths": ["/tmp"],
    "includedPaths": ["/tmp"],
    "jcr:primaryType": "oak:QueryIndexDefinition",
    "indexRules": {
      "jcr:primaryType": "nam:nt:unstructured",
      "nt:base": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
        "properties": {
          "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
          "binaryData": {
            "nodeScopeIndex": true,
            "propertyType": "Binary",
            "name": "jcr:data",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

Example query:
select * from [nt:base] where 
isdescendantnode('/tmp')
and contains(*, 'properties')
option(index tag [text])


Really thank you @Thomas, I'll read carefully and I'll some more tests to check what you stated, thank you for updating the documentation which is well done.

Hy Thomas, I tried to omit the setting of the binary property in index, but it didn't work, tika log about text extraction disappeared meaning that no indexing is happening...I believe.
As you suggested, I've created ad index on nt:base, indexing a single String property (just to have something in index), I've set jcr:mimetype in node and query like I did before, so contains(*, "a full word contained in binary").
Could you provide me a full code snippet showing what you stated?

You are right, I made a mistake! (I think the query picked another index when I tested...). I'm updating my answer.

Please let me know if this works for you, or not. I have used an index tag to ensure the query won't use the wrong index.

Yes it worked but they are all considerations that I had already arrived at empirically on my own. What really I don't understand is why to do a full text search in binary content I have to use contains(*,...), that is why does not it work with contains("binary", ...). I believe this behaviour was the same in jackrabbit 2.x.
And finally why nodescopeindex true is determinant to this test? What does really it mean that property? Yes I read the documentation but it is not so clear to me, I see in logs that with nodescopeindex many much more documents are indexed

"why does not it work with contains("binary", ...)" that is a good question! I didn't implement this part, somebody else did and we just inherited the code. For us the current behavior was OK so far. Now, with Elasticsearch, we also stumbled upon this strange behavior: it seems the index is much larger than needed, and contains things it should not! So yes, we are also not happy and want to change this. So far there is no Jira issue for this however, and I'm not sure when we will have time for it.
